# Why JavaFX properties have not getListeners() methods

Tags: javafx, properties, binding

I am using **JavaFX** properties since **JavaFX 8.0** , they seem to miss something appropriate i think . Let's say i add a change listener to a JavaFX Property :

```
 DoubleProperty doubleProp = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1);
 doubleProp.addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue)->{ ...code here }));
```

and i want to add 3 more including and `InvalidationListener`

Why to create an instances of `ChangeListener`[JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) or `InvalidationListener`[JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/InvalidationListener.html)?

Adding lines of code like :

```
 ChangeListener<? super Number> listener = (observable , oldValue , newValue) -> {
                    if (newValue.intValue() == 1)
                        //..... code
                };
```

all over the place isn't clear.

---

Why methods like these doesn't exist:

```
doubleProp.getChangeListeners().clearAll();
```

or

```
doubleProp.getChangeListeners().remove(doubleProp.getChangeListeners().get(0));
```

or

```
doubleProp.remove(doubleProp.getChangeListeners().get(0));
```

or

```
doubleProp.getInvalidationListeners().get(0));
```

Does JavaFX 9.0 has methods like these ? Is what i want a bad design ? I need to know the above :).

Comment: Not really sure I understand the point of the question. If you want to remove listeners later, you just keep a reference to them. That has never seemed to cause problems for me. Do you have a specific example where it is inconvenient somehow to do that? (You're also assuming that the listeners are kept in a way that is somehow ordered, such as in a list, which isn't necessarily the case.)

Comment: @James_D Hello :) Yes , i don't want to have to create instances . It would be wonderful to have a method `doubleProp.getChangeListeners().clearAll();` for example and clear all the Listeners or the one that i am selecting . **Like for example the items inside a FlowPane , i can get which i want using the default ObservableList and clear it**.

Comment: What do you mean "I don't want to have to create instances". If you don't "create instances", you don't have a listener in the first place. Allowing access to *all* listeners would break encapsulation: e.g. clearing all listeners from a control's `focusedProperty`, for example, would almost certainly break all sorts of internal functionality for most controls, including breaking the built-in CSS support.

Comment: @James_D How does for example  `DoubleProperty` holds the references of listeners , after using `addListener(...)` method  n times. It doesn't store them inside an `ObservableList`?,so when using `removeListener(...)` method the Listener is removed from the `ObservableList` . Why would be a problem to have access to that `ObservableList`? After all i can `removeListeners(...) n times to remove n listeners`;

Comment: How it stores the listeners is an implementation detail. It might use a list, a set, or something else entirely (IIRC in Swing, there is just a single listener. The `addXXXListener(...)` methods would create a new listener whose implementation method first invoked the method of the provided listener, and then invoked the implementation method of the existing listener. So there wasn't even a data structure per se; just a listener that potentially wrapped another listener, which potentially wrapped another listener, etc.)

Comment: @James_D O_O I see . I have an example of problem it is causing me . For example i have some `ChangeListeners` inside a method which are executing some code  [ which contains local variables from the method ] . So for example let's say that one of those listeners if fired and is calling one other method . But on the other method i want to remove all the listeners i added on the previous method , i can't . Ok i can create instances of those listeners outside the method scope , but then the problem is that i want to use the local variables from inside the listeners .

Comment: @James_D The only thing i can do for the above is to pass as arguments to the other method the `ChangeListeners` , and i have 5 of them . It's pollution of code :)

Comment: You should be able to refactor your methods so that the listeners are scoped to a single method. If not, then you have to make the listeners instance variables. You can consider creating an inner class that encapsulates the listeners and the two methods, for example. There are many ways to design these kinds of things that keep your code reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allowing access to a collection of all listeners on a property would be a bad design as it would break encapsulation for controls (or other objects) that used those properties. (Specifically, a control would likely want to expose a property while registering listeners on that property and keeping those listeners private. If the property exposed the listeners, this would become impossible.)

Just as one example, if `StringProperty` exposed a `ObservableList<ChangeListener<String>> getListeners()` method, then the API would make the following possible:

```
Label label = new Label("Some text");

label.textProperty().getListeners().clear();
```

This would *completely break the label*. The label's skin registers a listener with the label's `textProperty()`, that ensures the skin updates if the text is changed. If you remove this listener, which is the only possible result of executing the code above, then the label's skin would not know it had to resize or even display new text when you called `label.setText(...)`.

If you need to register a listener that you might need to remove, you just need to retain a reference to it. The overhead in code is minimal, i.e. there is not much difference between

```
label.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> { /* code */ });
```

and

```
ChangeListener<String> listener = (obs, oldText, newText) -> {/* code */} ;
label.textProperty().addListener(listener);
```

Comment: After carefull reading your answer , i have a question , if `label.textProperty().getListeners().clear();` would break the code , then why `label.textProperty().removeListener(...)` doesn't ?

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS Because neither the label nor the property give you access to the listener you are removing. (With the current API, what are you going to pass to `removeListener(...)`?) That's kind of the whole point. You are asking for an API that gives you access to a listener you should not have access to.

Answer (score 1):

@James_D, your explanation about what can go wrong when a listener is carelessly removed is good. However, this is really a *developer* problem, not *design*. Indeed, it is bad design for any 'add/remove' pattern *not* to also include access to whatever has been added.

For example, it may be useful to remove ("suspend") all the listeners *temporarily* in order to perform a process that changes the value (indeed several times) where the value at the end of the process is the same as the start; when the process is finished the listeners are added back ("restored"). While the 'reference' solution works for listeners you know about when designing a control, it doesn't help for listeners added by a developer using your control - these can't be referenced because you don't know what they will be. The 'suspend/restore' technique deals with this, it's up to the developer to use it properly and in the right situation.

JavaFX's property enhancements (object properties, bindings etc) are a huge improvement over Swing, like moving from a covered wagon to a Bugatti. However, the omission of a 'getListeners()' feature is a drawback.

Comment: _it is bad design for any 'add/remove' pattern not to also include access to whatever has been added_ Allow me to disagree ;) It might be true for a generic collection, but definitely not for listeners: each has its job to do without being hindered by any external entity. Allowing collaborators to remove any that they didn't add is breaking encapsulation. The ol' swing hacky interference is simply no longer possible and that's a good thing and it's by design.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and given your experience (you've probably forgotten more than I'll ever know) and you may disagree anytime. The point you make is a good one, it's the same made by James_D, and in principle I also agree. But there are cases, and in particular handling internal processes for a composite control, where having the ability to 'suspend/do something/restore' is very helpful. It can certainly be abused, but that - again - is the responsibility of the developer. Btw the same logic holds for JavaFX's extensive use of final methods and classes, but that's beyond the scope here.

Comment: I agree, that there cases where we want it :) But then, it's a deeper issue than allowing access to the listeners and do whatever we want with them: it's missing clean semantics of such a suspense/restore (which I agree also might be a good enhancement, and there are third party efforts on it). Without such, any access to the listeners is simply a hack on a potential path into desaster (exaggerating me ;)

Comment: FWIW it seems we agree more or less on the main points. Listeners or other behavior should never be added without good cause, and the same holds true for removing them. My objection is that by not making the listeners accessible because they might be removed for the wrong reasons is like someone making a decision for me about what is best for me, when I'm in just as good a position to make that decision myself. JavaFX is a big improvement over Swing in many areas, but on several points it goes too far by trying to 'protect' developers from themselves.